# Maven - Unable to set property value using profile based on property activation

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-profiles

I am trying to set a maven property value based on another property that is sent through the command line.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>desktop</id>
        <activation>
           <property>
               <name>environment</name>
               <value>desktop</value>
           </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
           <qTest.testCycleId>XXXXXX</qTest.testCycleId>
        </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I try to use the ***qTest.testCycleId*** in one of the plugin like below, I am getting property not resolved error.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>Upload Results to qTest</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>${script.executor}</executable>
          <commandlineArgs>${basedir}/scripts/qTest/QTestUploaderCucumber.sh
            ${basedir}
            ${qTest.testCycleId} ${qTest.projectId}
          </commandlineArgs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

PS - Property is resolved correctly if the profile is activated based on os family like below.

```
<profile>
  <id>Windows</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <family>Windows</family>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
     <qTest.testCycleId>XXXXXX</qTest.testCycleId>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

***Edit:***
As requested, please find the command line

```
mvn verify -DSUT=uat -Denvironment=desktop -DBrowser=chrome "-Dcucumber.options=--tags @Temp" -DforkCount=0 -e
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your command line call?

Comment: How are you passing the `environment` value? Please update your question with command.

Comment: @JF Meier - Added the requested information to the post. Thanks.

Comment: @Smile - Added the requested information to the post. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this looks alright to me ...

Comment: @JF Meier - For some reason it doesn't seem to work when I try to activate using property from command line. It works if I do it through OS. Weird!!!

Comment: @JagadeesanV I am not able to replicate this. Can you try printing value of `environment`? Probably you can use `echo-maven-plugin` and print `${environment}`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that it was due to a setting in Intellij. I had to check the environment checkbox under maven profiles.